# How can I serialize ExpandoObjects using snake_case with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize `ExpandoObjects` to JSON with Json.NET using snake_case property names. It seems as though the contract resolver isn't working as expected.

For example

```
dynamic test = new ExpandoObject();
test.TestProperty = "Value";
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() };
JObject result = JObject.FromObject(test, serializer);
string resultStr = result.ToString(); // { "TestProperty": "Value" }
```

If I change

```
serializer.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() };
```

to

```
serializer.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

then I get the expected camelCase results.

Also if I change the `ExpandoObject` to something like

```
class Test
{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}

Test test = new Test { TestProperty = "Value" };
```

then I get the expected `{ "test_property": "Value" }`.

This is ultimately part of a `JsonConverter` class, so I can't extract this code too much. It needs to eventually write json to a `JsonWriter` instance.

Comment: Hi Kris, I'm suggesting you cast ExpandoObject to a Dictionary of <string, object> values and iterate through it converting to a JSON (serialize it yourself). 
Seems like Json.NET has a bug there with the contract resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`NamingStrategy.ProcessDictionaryKeys = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy_ProcessDictionaryKeys.htm):

```
serializer.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver 
{ 
    NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy { ProcessDictionaryKeys = true } 
};
```

(This works because [`ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8) implements `IDictionary<String,Object>` and Json.NET serializes it as such.  Json.NET does have a [custom converter](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs) for *deserialization* of `ExpandoObject`, however the converter returns [`CanWrite = false`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs#L161) causing Json.NET to fall back on generic dictionary serialization code.)

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BIvCNa).

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly, thanks. It looks like the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` [sets this value to `true` by default](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/c5f210347055c43970199d4611993200d00977fd/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs#L49), which explains why that one works out of the box.